# Forcing browser tooltips to show immediately

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, tooltip

In *Firefox*, I have a small delay, (maybe half a second), before tooltips show up.

In *Chrome*, there's a similar delay, and a fade-in animation, making it even slower.

For some applications, this delay can become a serious annoyance.

@FF, I tried to look for variables in about:config, but didn't find anything about "title", "tooltips" or "fade".

Glancing at 3 pages of "add-ons" didn't help.

@Chrome : chrome:config fails to display (issue seems common), and chrome:flags didn't reveal anything worthy.

I Browsed the add-ons on marketplace, but found nothing.

Googling didn't help much more.

Does anyone know a trick for that ?

Did I miss an add-on somewhere ?

Any other solution ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the website and the implementation of the tooltip in question you might not be able to influence the behavior. It might be good to include a screenshot or an example.

Comment: The precise reason which made me ask is [Innovation](https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=innovation), a web-implemented boardgame on Boardgamearena

But there is other circumstances where I'd like or need to disable this kind of animations, the same way I disabled most of Aero quirks on Windows, so generic solutions would be a good thing.

_The "game demonstration" beyond my link lets you see the feature in its technical context, better than any screenshot.  Looks like it needs to be logged, though._

Comment: Not really, because it would require me to register in order to see anything. If, what you're talking about, is richer than a simple text popup in a square box (e. g. might be caused by [img alt tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) or [title tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_Attributes/title)) you're looking at something more complex and it's unlikely that you will find a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by making a new value in `about:config` called `ui.tooltipDelay`. Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/ui.tooltipDelay)!

In this example, I've set it to 50ms. You can set it to as low as 1ms if you wish.

[image: about:config screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the input.
Right answer, but didn't help : I guess most tooltips are now, "emulated" using javascript.  In my case, all I got is it uses the "Dojo" framework, but I couldn't find which component (or *function* !) I should target to alter the transition.

At least, I learnt that some about:config values aren't populated by default (now, I'll just wonder... *why* ? :p)

Comment: Yes, if the website uses a custom JS solution to implement tooltips then there's not much you can do.